# I'm calling MS-Graph from Logic App and getting an "Unauthorized" error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I get an "Unauthorized" status code (401) when I call MS Graph from my Logic App.

The MS Gaph URI I'm calling has been tested separately using Graph Explorer to insure that it was a properly formed request.

I'm guessing that the issue has to do with Application Permissions needing to be granted to the AD App registration.

The Logic App is not prompting the user to grant the "Delegated" permissions I added to the App Registration.  This is why I'm guessing, I need to use Application permissions instead of Delegated permissions.

Here is the error being returned
    `{
      "error": {
        "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
        "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be 
    understood.",
        "innerError": {
          "request-id": "8addc6d3-fbf1-4a61-8ed2-b4593a10dd8c",
          "date": "2019-07-16T12:29:27"
        }
      }
    }`

I would of course Grant the Application permissions myself in order to test this, but I don't have rights, and I need to research this a bit before I approach our admins.

Comment: Which API `URL` you are trying call from logic app?

Comment: Graph API.  I'm reading the User's Calendar information.

Comment: @CaiyiJu:  Thanks for your answer.  I'm still relatively new to this.  The links you left in your answer are also helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You need grant the **application permissions** to your app. The Active Directory OAuth in logic app uses [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which doesn't need user interaction.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions) is the difference between application permission and delegated permission.